# Is there a way to independently control media volume on left and right channels?

Tags: codenameone

For codename1, I know that a Media object allows the output volume to be set, across both channels, using the setVolume() method.

Is there any way to control the volume of the two channels separately?  I.e. Is there a way to achieve balance control or independent control of the volume levels for each channel of a stereo output?  I am targeting both Android and IOS with the Codenameone codebase.

My application requires independent channel control, and I'm rather desperately looking for a solution.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Codename One doesn't have that capability yet. You may achieve this through NativeInterface.

Comment: I can verify that @Diamond is indeed correct and should submit it as an answer. Check out the Dr. Sbaitso demo for a sample of native interfaces to play TTS audio which might help you get started with your own native interfaces: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dr-sbaitso-revisited.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One doesn't have that capability yet. You may achieve this through `NativeInterface`. Check out the [Dr. Sbaitso demo](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dr-sbaitso-revisited.html) for a sample of native interfaces to play TTS audio which might help you get started with your own native interfaces.

Comment: Based on @Shai's comment under your question.